# How to dynamically show/hide Looker Studio bar charts based on dropdown selection?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm working on a Looker Studio project where I have two separate bar charts on a page, and I want to implement a feature that allows users to dynamically show/hide these charts based on a selection made in a dropdown field.

Here's the scenario: I have a dropdown field with options "Chart1" and "Chart2". When a user selects "Chart1" from the dropdown, I want Chart2 to be hidden and only Chart1 to be visible, and vice versa when the user selects "Chart2". Essentially, I need to create a mechanism to toggle the visibility of the charts based on the dropdown selection.

I've explored Looker's documentation, but couldn't find a straightforward solution for this specific requirement. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this functionality in Looker Studio? Any insights, code snippets, or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.